# How can ensure the PROCEDURE can run all successfully in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

Here is my PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_active_account`(IN i_email VARCHAR(255), 
IN i_active_code VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    DELETE FROM activeCodes WHERE active_code = i_active_code;
    UPDATE users SET status = 1 WHERE email = i_email;
    COMMIT;   
END
```

I got a problem here, I would like to execute `DELETE FROM activeCodes WHERE active_code = i_active_code` success, if this line cannot run success (For example, it can't delete any things), the `UPDATE users SET status = 1 WHERE email = i_email` can not be executed. How can I focus this behaviour? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check mysql_affected_rows. if greater than 0, then there definitely has been a delete. Hope that helps